# How do I modify all files in a decending folder structure using powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to update all files with the .xml file extension within a descending folder structure but my script is failing (likely due to lack of knowledge). Any help would be great:

```
#Example of syntax
#=======================
# seekAndReplace -FilePath "\\sitecollection\newroot\pages" -FileExtension 
# "*.xml" -OldAddress "http://oldroot/sites/blank/" -NewAddress "http://newroot/sites/blank"
#


function seekAndReplace {
Param(
[string]$FilePath,
[string]$FileExtension,
[string]$OldAddress,
[string]$NewAddress
)
$files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter $FileExtension
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        (Get-Content $file.fullname) |
        ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $OldAddress,$NewAddress} |
        Set-Content $file.fullname
    } #end foreach
} #end function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help? Notice the use of the [Regex Escape method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx). You need it to escape special characters.

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter $FileExtension | Foreach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_.fullname) -replace [regex]::Escape($OldAddress),$NewAddress | Set-Content $_.fullname
}
```